# Formatting a USB flash drive as ext4

Tags: live-usb, ext4, persistence

I'm making a custom bootable USB flash drive with a persistent partition. Formatting the partition as ext2 obviously makes the filesystem very sensitive to improper unmounting. I remember a while back that Ubuntu (and other distributions) had problems when Flash memory was formatted as ext3/4, writing data so frequently that the flash drives died very quickly.

Have these issues now been resolved? Is there any reason to not use a journaled filesystem when formatting a USB flash drive?

Comment: I can't speak for this on a broad scale, but my 8GB Sandisk recently died. It was formatted ext4 at the time, but granted I format and flashed it **a lot** throughout its life (about 3 years).

Comment: To be fair, 3 years is pretty decent for a consumer-level flash drive. With the issues that I remember reading about, flash memory could be killed within _days_, not years.

Comment: How is the duration related to the kind of filesystem? I used my first USB-Stick for more than 10 years with reiserfs without problem - it died later in the washing machine. :) But I admit, that I used it only occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

I use the ext4 file system and turn off journaling in USB drives and memory cards. I also set the mount option '`noatime`' in `/etc/fstab` in an installed system. See these links:

- [Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS)
- [Pendrive lifetime](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13199297#post13199297)
- [Lifespan of a flash drive running Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588035/lifespan-a-flash-drive-running-ubuntu)

Finally, ***backup*** the system or at least your personal data at regular intervals and whenever important data are stored!

Answer (score 0):

I think that usb drive's every cell has it's own **limit number of read/write.**
So journaling is not used.
solving this problem may be very difficult.

Comment: Journaling is always used if you use ext4. The question is how much this affects the longevity of the flash drive.

Comment: A program operation followed by an erase operation constitutes a program/erase cycle. Typically NAND ﬂash can withstand 100,000 cycles for SLC type or 10,000 for MLC type. And journaling area is fixed in small space. So journaling area can  be destroyed faster than other area.

Answer (score 0):

Even if there were I'd still journal the USB stick. There is a slim possibility that it would increase the wear on the drive, but it's not nearly as certain as the fact that if you mistakenly fail to `umount` the thing properly one time you will be boned. The answer is buy more drives when they wear out, not turn off the only protection the filesystem has against damage.