# Install Lubuntu on a pendrive - advice

Tags: lubuntu, live-usb, usb-installation

Hi I want to install Lubuntu on a pendrive to use to run somo codes and make some graphs. It is a good idea or should buy another type of external memory?
I read that the usb pendrive usually becomes very hot and slow when used like this and they stop to work soon..
What are your advices?

Comment: Having Ubuntu on USB flash drive is absolutely normal. But you should choose pen drive with reasonable write speed (> 10 Mb/s) and capacity (>= 16 Gb) for comfortable usage. I recommend SanDisk Ultra or Exteme. I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS [MATE](http://ubuntu-mate.org/) on such flash and it boots normally on any PC and/or laptop wherever I am.

Comment: so you recommend me Ubuntu 16.04 instead o Lubuntu on a fast perndrive?

Comment: I recommend Ubuntu MATE on fast pen drive. Lubuntu is usually for old hardware, it works fast but is less user-friendly.

Comment: Ubuntu on pendrive runs in RAM if there is enough RAM and should be fast. Lifespan see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/588035/lifespan-a-flash-drive-running-ubuntu