# Install Ubuntu on a micro SD card class 10 512GB

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, lts, sd-card, syslinux

I'm tryning to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a micro SD Card as described above.
But I am getting this error message:

XDG_URNTIME_DIR (/run/user/999) is owned by us (uid 0), but by uid 999! (This could e.g. happen if you try to connect to a non-root PulseAudio as a root user, over the native protocol. Don't to that.)

Also the benchmark of the disk is not delivering the desired Read/Write rate, being around 17/8 MBs R/W, I would like to know if this is a physical limitation of the card reader, a drive or Bios energy device control problem, like acpi or a problem with the card meaning it's damaged or not being an original sandisk.

Comment: Have you tried booting the card in a different computer? You could try installing using an image file, not much can go wrong there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Creating a Full install Ubuntu SD card from a Pre-built Image File.

**If working in Windows:**

- Download Image File: https://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/dd_unb_ubuntu-20.04_15GB_2020-06-26.img.xz (provided by sudodus) MD5SUM's can be found here: https://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/grub-boot-templates-for-uefi-n-bios.md5.
- Download Rufus*: https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/releases/download/v3.11/rufus-3.11.exe
- Double click Rufus exe file.
- Select SD card as Target drive in Rufus.
- Select above Image File in Rufus.
- Click Rufus start button.
- Wait for flashing to complete... Done.

(Password is "changeme", change it),

The SD card should boot on almost any modern X86-64 computer.

Thanks to sudodus for the image file.

In Windows it may be necessary to install 7Zip before proceeding. Rufus will use it when working with the .xz image: https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1900-x64.exe

**If working in Ubuntu:** you can use **mkusb**, **Disks** or **Etcher** to flash the SD card. P7zzip may be needed to extract the image.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for this solution, haven't tried it out yet. Shouldn't the speed limit of the sd card affect the performance of the system? I think is mostly due my card reader which I think doesn't support UHS - l

Comment: My understanding is that Ubuntu will mainly run in RAM if the computer has enough RAM. In that case the read/write speed at startup or when saving data.

Comment: @C. S. Cameron, Should I be worried about wearing out my sd card using it for this? I'm between this solution and making a persistent live session on a 16GB pen drive, as a more experienced user, what would you suggest? I also want to use half of the card storage for Windows installed in other volume.

Comment: @Andre Gomes Ferreira de Olivei: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/588035/lifespan-a-flash-drive-running-ubuntu Note that nowadays they have been adding more layers in order to increase speed and reduce costs. They say that this also reduces endurance and life time. However consider that SD cards used in security cameras endure continuous writes for long periods of time. Even a Full install USB does not spend that much of it's time writing.

Comment: Hello, again. Hey, it didn`t work :/ seems like my card has a  mbr partition and this can`t be changed, when I check the partition on gparted it`s says the GPT partition is corrupted, but the primary is ok, besides it doesn`t show up in Bios device manager.