# Persistent or Install Ubuntu in my USB linked with temporal files

Tags: usb, live-usb, persistence

well I have this question, I want to install ubuntu (not live) in my usb. The thing is I'm worried because it seems, that this method is not recommended because will force the system to write temporary files on the flash drive, and with limited number of writes allowed on the flash drive, it can suddenly get corrupted and become unusable. So I don't know how great this idea is, I'm scare to do this procedure, and destruct my computer. In other comments I read in the web, and they talk about the advantages, but not about the cons. So I want to know which one is better in terms of keeping my computer safe, and not forcing my computer to do stuff, that I will be regretting later.

Comment: In terms of writing a normal installation in a USB flash drive or live with persistence is the same.

Comment: I have been installing Ubuntu to USB for over 15 years and am still using the first USB I installed to. I understand that some newer multi layer flash drives are not as long lasting as they are mainly designed for speed and capacity, not endurance. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/588035/lifespan-a-flash-drive-running-ubuntu The only time a USB has harmed my computer is due to having a virus on it, not from a Full install.

Comment: Thanks to both of you!